# CakePHP and VirtualDocumentRoot issue

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a LAMP server configured with `DocumentRoot /var/www` changed to `VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-3/` in the Apache2 config file - this allows me to automatically map `/var/www/<subdomain>` to `<subdomain>.example.com`.

I'm currently in the process of learning CakePHP (2.x), with Cake in directory `/var/www/foo/`; I've noticed that the URLS aren't redirecting properly, and am attempting to resolve this issue; as per `http://bit.ly/KmEhHl`, I've modified the default .htaccess file to (among other things):

```
RewriteBase /cake
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

But this raises a 500 Internal Server Error - checking Apache2's `error.log` and `rewrite.log`, this is because `.htaccess` is causing an infinite redirect, and is appending `app/webroot` to the URI.

From my understanding, the `L` flag here should indicate 'last rule' - I'm assuming that this error is due to my poor understanding of `mod_rewrite`, but I'm not sure exactly where this is happening. Would the error be because of some other latent issue with this setup? I'm aware that there have been several questions on this already, and will update if any new information can be found on my end. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you should set up your environment with virtual hosts - this would fix all your problems at the source: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/05/29/working-with-domains-locally/ (and no rewrite base stuff required)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found an answer!

Full answer courtesy of user 'kostasz' at http://bit.ly/NSDWE2 in comments.

The hint was indeed the infinite  redirect - using `RewriteBase /cake` was not the correct base URL.

To fix this issue, add `RewriteBase /` to each of the `.htaccess` files in `/`, `/app/`, and `/app/webroot/`.

Comment: That combine with explicitly adding <Directory>AllowOverride All</Directory>